# error validating username check

Tags: php, validation

Been having a problems with my form validating, everything works fine except when it checks for username which also works but checks if the username is avaliable before and after it has been inserted into the table, so keep getting username is not avaliable
The code is looks like this

```
   Function get()
  {
    $error = array();
    $sth = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :user');
    $sth->execute(array(':user' => $_POST['username']));
    $count = $sth->rowCount();
    If($count > 0)
    {
     $error['avaliable'] = 'The username is not avaliable';
    }
    If(!empty($error))
    {
      Return $error;
    }else{
    //insert codes goes here
   }
   }
```

Comment: Its not clear, whats the problem? it always says the username is not available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your control statement is wrong here. try something like this,

```
    Function get()
  {
    $error = array();
    $sth = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = :user');
    $sth->execute(array(':user' => $_POST['username']));
    $count = $sth->rowCount();
    If($count == 0)
    {
     //insert codes goes here
    }
    else If($count > 0)
    {
     $error['avaliable'] = 'The username is avaliable';
    }
    If(!empty($error))
    {
      Return $error;
    }
   }
```